# Why does my UART Kernel Module not send the last 8 characters of my message?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am building a UART Kernel Module with the RTDM API. For the datasheet of this AUART, I worked with chapter 30 of the following link: [Link of datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MCIMX28RM.pdf)

The driver is very basic, it only has to send a buffer which is passed to it in user-space with `write` function. It works like this:

1. In `open` function, activate UART with `UARTEN` bit of UART Control Register
2. In `write` function, I activate the Transmitter with TXE bit of UART Control Register
3. Then, start sending characters with:

```c
static void rt_mxs_auart_tx_chars(struct rt_mxs_auart_ctx *ctx)

{
    int ch;
    pr_info("Start transmitting\n");

    while (ctx->out_npend > 0 &&
           !(mxs_read(ctx->port, REG_STAT) & AUART_STAT_TXFF)) {

        ch = ctx->out_buf[ctx->out_head++];
        mxs_write(ch, ctx->port, REG_DATA);
        ctx->out_head &= (OUT_BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
        ctx->out_npend--;
    }

    if (mxs_read(ctx->port, REG_STAT) & AUART_STAT_TXFF){
        pr_info("We've stopped transmitting because FIFO is full, remains: %d to be sent (bytes pending)\n", ctx->out_npend);
    }
    if(ctx->out_npend > 0 ) {
        mxs_set(AUART_INTR_TXIEN, ctx->port, REG_INTR);
        pr_info("%d bytes pending, setting AUART_INTR_TXIEN\n", ctx->out_npend);
    }
    else {
        mxs_clr(AUART_INTR_TXIEN, ctx->port, REG_INTR);
        pr_info("%d bytes pending, clearing AUART_INTR_TXIEN\n", ctx->out_npend);
    }
}
```

`TXIEN` corresponds to `Transmit Interrupt Enable`, and `AUART_STAT_TXFF` means that the transmit FIFO is full. Here's the ctx structure:

```
struct rt_mxs_auart_ctx {
    struct rtser_config config; /* current device configuration */

    rtdm_irq_t irq_handle;      /* device IRQ handle */
    rtdm_lock_t lock;       /* lock to protect context struct */

    int in_head;            /* RX ring buffer, head pointer */
    int in_tail;            /* RX ring buffer, tail pointer */
    size_t in_npend;        /* pending bytes in RX ring */
    int in_nwait;           /* bytes the user waits for */
    rtdm_event_t in_event;      /* raised to unblock reader */
    char in_buf[IN_BUFFER_SIZE];    /* RX ring buffer */

    volatile unsigned long in_lock; /* single-reader lock */
    uint64_t *in_history;       /* RX timestamp buffer */

    int out_head;           /* TX ring buffer, head pointer */
    int out_tail;           /* TX ring buffer, tail pointer */
    size_t out_npend;       /* pending bytes in TX ring */
    rtdm_event_t out_event;     /* raised to unblock writer */
    char out_buf[OUT_BUFFER_SIZE];  /* TX ring buffer */
    rtdm_mutex_t out_lock;      /* single-writer mutex */

    uint64_t last_timestamp;    /* timestamp of last event */
    int ioc_events;         /* recorded events */
    rtdm_event_t ioc_event;     /* raised to unblock event waiter */
    volatile unsigned long ioc_event_lock;  /* single-waiter lock */

    int ier_status;         /* IER cache */
    int mcr_status;         /* MCR cache */
    int status;         /* cache for LSR + soft-states */
    int saved_errors;       /* error cache for RTIOC_GET_STATUS */

    /*
     * The port structure holds all the information about the UART
     * port like base address, and so on.
     */
    struct rt_mxs_auart_port *port;
};
```

In my interrupt handler, I do this:

```
    if (istat & AUART_INTR_TXIS){
        pr_info("Transmit Interrupt Status enabled\n");
        rt_mxs_auart_tx_chars(ctx);
        istat &= ~AUART_INTR_TXIS;
        ret = RTDM_IRQ_HANDLED;
    }
```

which means that if the interrupt status flag is active, we send data again with the same function `rt_mxs_auart_tx_chars`

My **problem** is that I do not seem to receive the end of my message. For example, if I try to send "This... is my second message" (29 char) I only get "This... is my sec" (17 char). The log is the following:

```
Calling open function
Calling write function
Enabling Transmitter
Start transmitting
We've stopped transmitting because FIFO is full, remains: 12 to be sent (bytes pending)
12 bytes pending, setting AUART_INTR_TXIEN
IRQ handler called
Transmit Interrupt Status enabled
Start transmitting
We've stopped transmitting because FIFO is full, remains: 4 to be sent (bytes pending)
4 bytes pending, setting AUART_INTR_TXIEN
Receive Interrupt Status or Receive Timeout Interrupt Status enabled
IRQ handler called
Transmit Interrupt Status enabled
Start transmitting
0 bytes pending, clearing AUART_INTR_TXIEN
Disabling Transmitter
```

How do you think can I correct this?

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  How is `ctx` initialized?  What exactly is `ctx->out_head &= (OUT_BUFFER_SIZE - 1);` supposed to do?

Comment: Are your sending/receiving UART's configured for any kind of hard/soft handshaking?

Comment: You are right, sorry for that.  ctx->out_head is the head pointer of the TX ring buffer and out_npend is the number of pending bytes in TX ring. The whole bit in the while loop is supposed to take a char from the circular buffer, write it in data register, replace head pointer and recalculate the number of bytes pending, until the TX fifo is full

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the ctx setup code.  I am still wondering why you perform two operations on ctx->out_head in the loop?  That one line I mentioned above, just doesn't look right.  Unless you have some magic in mind that I am seeing?

Comment: @jwdonahue the line you were referring to is there to check if the circular buffer is full or not, as you can see for example in the "Push data into Buffer" section of the following link : https://elexfocus.com/implement-a-circular-buffer-in-c/